# Senkey() doesnt work in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

Hi I'm new to selenium and java. I tried to enter phone numbers in the field but sendkey doesnt work and it gives an error `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element`

below is the code I used.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content column']/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/form/b/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/input")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content column']/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/form/b/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/input")).sendKeys("123456789");
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: its internal site. i can log in successfully with my credentials. https://marswebtdc.tdc.vzwcorp.com/cdl/lte/fdr_llc/fdr.jsp?3gOr4g=4g

Comment: wrong url provided cannot access

Comment: copy the client side html and paste it here

Comment: you need to login first . for that i can login programmatically but after that  sendkeys doesnt work on the field that i want to enter phone numbers

Comment: what do you mean client side html?

Comment: @tonylee Have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: possible duplicate of [sendkey() doesnt work in selenium webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122218/sendkey-doesnt-work-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

if your xpath is correct (and if you generated it in google chrome, as it appears you did, then it very likely is correct), then you should try an [explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

often times, your software will run much faster than the page can load, so it's searching for an attribute that isn't present.  make your code wait, and report back.

Comment: idriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); but it sitll gives same error

Comment: first, note that there's a difference b/w implicit and explicit waits.  `explicit` will wait as long as you've directed it **OR** `until` your attribute is present.  second, assuming that 15 seconds is more than enough time for your browser to load the attribute you're seeking, then the problem probably isn't only a `wait` issue.  can you please edit your answer to include a code snippet of the html you're looking for?

Comment: you're right it doesn't (at least not in python).  you're working in Java, so I don't know your answer, but I know that `sendkeys()` will not work for every field.  sometimes you have to execute some javascript before you can send information.  often times, though, I find that the problem's in my code -- i.e., I'm not accessing the element correctly b/c it's in an `iframe` or something.

Comment: I would re post your question with more information (what you've tried, what you're trying to do, and code so SO users can test it), and tag the question as `java,` so more people see it.